# How do you find the radio buttons not clicked?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a radio group used for setting the properties of a data class, specifically a sandwich. Here is how I have it so far: I manually set the sandwiches visible if the sandwich was checked, and manually set the sandwiches invisible if it was the not chosen one. I want to streamline this by using a function, but I'm not sure how to find the not chosen radio button ids. I'm new to both Kotlin and Android, so any help would be appreciated.

```
fun onSandwichRadioButtonClicked(view: View) {
        if (view is RadioButton) {
            // Is the button now checked?
            val checked = view.isChecked

            // Check which radio button was clicked
            when (view.getId()) {
                R.id.panini_button ->
                    if (checked) {
                        sandwich.sandwichCost = 7.0f
                        sandwich.name = "Panini"
                        binding.panini.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.hoagie.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.sandwich.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                R.id.hoagie_button ->
                    if (checked) {
                        sandwich.sandwichCost = 10.0f
                        sandwich.name = "Hoagie"
                        binding.panini.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.hoagie.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.sandwich.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                R.id.sandwich_button ->
                    if (checked) {
                        sandwich.sandwichCost = 5.0f
                        sandwich.name = "Sandwich"
                        binding.panini.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.hoagie.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.sandwich.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
            }
            sandwich.totalCost = (sandwich.extraCost + sandwich.sandwichCost).toString()
            binding.invalidateAll()
            Toast.makeText(
                activity, "Total Cost :" +
                        " ${sandwich.totalCost}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }

    fun setSandwich(sandwichName: String, sandwichCost: Float, sandwichImage: ImageView){
        sandwich.sandwichCost = sandwichCost
        sandwich.name = sandwichName
        sandwichImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        //set the remaining sandwiches to invisible. how do I find these sandwiches?
```

the related xml code:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/panini"
            android:layout_width="192dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.411"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_food_obvious_panini"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hoagie"
            android:layout_width="149dp"
            android:layout_height="153dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.394"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/hoagie"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sandwich"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="311dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.345"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sandwhichanddrink"
            tools:visibility="visible" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/sandwichRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tomatoes_check"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.88">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/sandwich_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onSandwichRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/sandwich"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/hoagie_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onSandwichRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/hoagie"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/panini_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onSandwichRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/panini"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

UPDATE: I've streamlined it a little bit but I feel like it could still be better. The ArrayList of Image views is my current workaround:

```
fun onSandwichRadioButtonClicked(view: View) {

        var notChosenSandwiches: ArrayList<ImageView> = ArrayList()
        if (view is RadioButton) {
            // Is the button now checked?
            val checked = view.isChecked

            // Check which radio button was clicked
            when (view.getId()) {
                R.id.panini_button ->
                    if (checked) {
                        notChosenSandwiches.clear()
                        notChosenSandwiches.add(binding.hoagie)
                        notChosenSandwiches.add(binding.sandwich)
                        setSandwich("Panini", 7.0f, binding.panini, notChosenSandwiches)
                    }
                R.id.hoagie_button ->
                    if (checked) {
                        notChosenSandwiches.clear()
                        notChosenSandwiches.add(binding.panini)
                        notChosenSandwiches.add(binding.sandwich)
                        setSandwich("Hoagie", 10.0f, binding.hoagie, notChosenSandwiches)
                    }
                R.id.sandwich_button ->
                    if (checked) {
                        notChosenSandwiches.clear()
                        notChosenSandwiches.add(binding.hoagie)
                        notChosenSandwiches.add(binding.panini)
                        setSandwich("Melt", 5.0f, binding.sandwich, notChosenSandwiches)
                    }
            }
            sandwich.totalCost = (sandwich.extraCost + sandwich.sandwichCost).toString()
            binding.invalidateAll()
            Toast.makeText(
                activity, "Total Cost :" +
                        " ${sandwich.totalCost}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }

    /**
     * update the sandwich and the views
     *
     * @param sandwichName the new name of the sandwich
     * @param sandwichCost the new cost of the sandwich
     * @param shownImage the image of the sandwich
     * @param hideThese the not chosen sandwiches
*/
    fun setSandwich(sandwichName: String, sandwichCost: Float, shownImage: ImageView, hideThese: ArrayList<ImageView>){
        sandwich.sandwichCost = sandwichCost
        sandwich.name = sandwichName
        shownImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        for (image in hideThese)
            image.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```

Comment: you can get the value of the radio button clicked, & the rest in view group would be unclicked...isn't it?

Comment: Can you post the associated XML layout file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your problem that you know the ID of the selected button, and you want to have a list of all the other (unselected) IDs so you can do something useful with them?

It doesn't look like `RadioGroup` will give you a list of its buttons (just which one is currently selected) so you might have to generate that yourself. It's a subclass of `LinearLayout` so it's not doing anything complicated, it just has all of the `RadioButton`s as direct children, so you can do this:

```
sandwichButtons = sandwichRadioGroup.children
    .filterIsInstance(RadioButton::class.java).toList()
```

which gives you a `List<RadioButton>`. Or if you just want their IDs:

```
    sandwichButtonIds = sandwichRadioGroup.children
    .filterIsInstance(RadioButton::class.java)
    .map { it.id }
    .toList()
```

Which is a `List<Int>` with all their IDs (the `R.id.hoagie` values). If you make that a `lateinit var` field, and assign with the lookup during `onCreate` or `onViewCreated` or something, you'll have yourself a nice list of all the radio buttons in your group. Then you can do this stuff:

```
val unselected = sandwichButtonIds.minus(selectedId)
```

There's probably a lot of things that would help with what you're doing, but I can only guess at this point, so hopefully that's a start! Also "a data class, specifically a sandwich" gets an upvote from me